# How can i get to use a button in my Fragment on my MainActivity or use gmap widget from my activity in my fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, onclicklistener

I am creating an app that shows means of transportation in an area, it has a 3 page ViewPager with only one fragment (I didn't want to create a lot of fragments for all the 3 means of transportation i presently have), but my problem is that I want to have access to the fragments button on the MainActivity so that when clicked it calls the GoogleMap object which is in the MainActivity and I can display the markers or even have access to the GoogleMap object in my fragment (even better) so I can manipulate it as I want, but any code I write gives me a null pointer on the button.

This is the main class:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottom_view_on_successful_pick_layout = findViewById(R.id.bottom_view_on_successful_pick_layout);

       GoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient
                .Builder(this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, this)
                .build();

        autoCompleteAdapter = new PlaceAutocompleteAdapter(this, Places.getGeoDataClient(this, null), LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);



        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(MainActivity.this);


        RideOptionFragment rideOptionFragment =  RideOptionFragment.newInstance(new RideOption("cars", "1"));

        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(MainActivity.this);

        ViewPager viewPager = findViewById(R.id.ride_option_ViewPager);

        rideOptionPageAdapter = new RideOptionPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),cc);

        viewPager.setAdapter(rideOptionPageAdapter);

        rideOptionFragment.rideRequestBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // do somthing to google map ere

            }
        });
    }
```

This is the ride option adapter:

```
public class RideOptionPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public int position = 0;



    public RideOption[] rideOptions = {

            new RideOption("car", "1"),
            new RideOption("biycle", "2"),
            new RideOption("boat", "3")


    };

    public RideOptionFragment rof;

    public RideOptionPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, RideOptionFragment rr){
        super(fm);

        rof = rr;    
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return rideOptions.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        rof = RideOptionFragment.newInstance(rideOptions[position]);

        return  rof;

    }    
}
```

This is my fragment:

```
RideOption rideOption = new RideOption("pullova", "pullova_");

    CircleImageView circleImageView;
```

public Button rideRequestBtn;

```
public static RideOptionFragment newInstance(RideOption rideOption) {

        RideOptionFragment rideOptionFragment = new RideOptionFragment();       
        rideOptionFragment.rideOption = rideOption;    
        return rideOptionFragment;
        }



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view  = inflater.inflate(R.layout.ride_option_layout, container, false);

        rideRequestBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.ride_request);

        circleImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.pullova_ride_option_image);
            circleImageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(getResources().getIdentifier(rideOption.getImage_URL(), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName())));

        rideRequestBtn.setText(rideOption.getName());


        return view;

        }
```

This is the error I get :

> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)'
>   on a null object reference
>                         at com.pullova.pullovatechnologies.pullovaandroidproject.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:228)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6664)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)  W/art:
>   Verification of

Comment: Did you already check whether the ID of the button is the correct one? Is the id of the button in the XML sheet ride_request?

Comment: @ProgFroz yes, i did

Comment: One Theory I have, is that you may call the Button before the rideRequestBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.ride_request); is initiated.

Comment: @ProgFroz same theory i have to, but how is that possible

Answer (score 1):

The reason why you're getting this error is that the `FragmentPagerAdapter` doesn't load the fragments synchronously. At the point you are calling `setOnClickListener` the button reference is null because `onCreateView` of the fragment hasn't been called yet.

Also, you are instantiating a fragment in the activity and maintaining a reference to one of its buttons, but your adapter's `getItem` method actually creates another instance of the fragment, which means the fragment you created in the activity is never used.

Instead of setting the `OnClickListener` from the activity, do it directly from the fragment, within `onCreateView`. This way you have access to everything else within that fragment. If instead you need access to something from the activity when the button is tapped, you can call `((MainActivity) getActivity()).myCustomFunction();` and write the rest of the code within `myCustomFunction()`, where you have access to everything else within the MainActivity.